# Как работает shader program в opengl?

Tags: c++, opengl

Что я делаю:
считываю текст из файла, компилирую вершинный шейдер.
считываю текст из файла, компилирую фрагментный шейдер.
создаю шейдерную программу glCreateProgram, привязываю шейдеры glAttachShader, выполняю glLinkProgram.
Дальше для каждой переменной если она изменилась, то я устанавливаю значение в шейдерной программе с помощью glUniformMatrix4fv.
Дальше я сделал как бы split screen, а именно с помощью glViewport отрисовываю сначала на одной половине окна, затем на другой. Нужно, чтобы на разных частях экрана был нарисован один и тот же объект, но под разными углами и/или смещённый.

Для этого я аналогично первой половине создал для второй половины экрана пары переменных типов glm::mat4 и bool, в bool хранится, изменилась ли переменная типа glm::mat4.

Меняю значение переменной для одной стороны экрана, но отображение меняется у обоих.
Пришёл к выводу, что шейдерная программа хранит в себе значения переменных из прошлого вызова.
Какие есть решения, чтобы не посылать каждый кадр для каждой половины экрана переменные в шейдер?
Как я сделал:
повторно компилирую шейдеры, создаю вторую шейдерную программу, добавляю в нее только что скомпилированные шейдеры, линкую ей эти шейдеры.
После выбора части экрана с помощью glViewPort вызываю glUseProgram, после этого, если переменные изменились, то отправляю их в шейдерную программу, затем отрисовка.
Это работает.

Но думаю, что можно сделать как-то лучше. Если я буду отображать несколько объектов, то каждому нужно создавать шейдерную программу? (ещё и по 2 раза в моём случае)

использованы библиотеки glad, glm, glfw. язык С++.

Comment: Решение заключается как раз в отправке переменных каждый раз, либо сразу отправлять массив переменных для всех случаев и каждый раз выбирать из него конкретную по номеру инстанса.

Comment: @user7860670
как работает эта отправка переменных? компьютер же копирует участок из оперативной памяти в память видеокарты? насколько это затратно? есть ли смысл отправлять переменные по 2 раза за кадр, если они не изменились? или быстрее будет работать, если создавать дополнительные шейдерные программы для второй половины экрана и менять уже в этой шейдерной программе по необходимости, переключая шейдерные программы по 2 раза за кадр? или я могу в этой шейдерной программе линковать другой шейдер, в нём другие переменные? где именно хранятся uniform, в шейдере или в шейдерной программе?

Comment: Вам стоит задавать один вопрос в вопросе... Буферов должно быть как можно меньше, переключатся они должны как можно реже. То же еще в большей степени относится и к шейдерам. Для каких-то учебных целей это все наверное не столь важно. https://developer.nvidia.com/content/constant-buffers-without-constant-pain-0

Comment: @user7860670
быстрее перемножать матрицы (projection, view, model) процессором и отправлять в шейдерную программу всего одну матрицу, умножать на неё координаты вершин шейдерной программой или быстрее отправлять несколько матриц и перемножать шейдерной программой?

Comment: Ну если матрица не меняется между вызовами - то лучше один раз посчитать, а если постоянно меняется - то лучше разгрузить CPU. Однако тут еще вопрос размера этих матриц. Так что делайте тесты и замеряйте время.